# Is there any chance for connecting to online database in a host machine?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

With an Android app, for example can i let it connect to SQLite Manager(Firefox Plugin)'s database or some other database which is on host from different devices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way. the only way is through web API's that wrap the dealing of the server side DB.